# trouble importing google services

Tags: android, sdk

am having a problem with android, I have a project in eclipse, these are the errors:

```
the import com.google.android.gms.wearable.internal.ar cannot be resolved
the import com.google.android.gms.internal.ob cannot be resolved
```

I already added google-play-services.jar as we can see in this pic
[image]

and this is what I have in the SDK manager
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Android development in Eclipse can be a frustrating experience.

If the flexibility is there, I would strongly recommend moving over to Android Studio: http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/index.html

Comment: that's exactly what I'm trying to do, but I cannot export the project with errors...It's very frustrating